# What is the interaction between Secure Text Entry and Autocorrection for a UITextField?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield

When using a `UITextField` in an iOS app, I can set secure text entry to `YES`, which will obscure all but the last character typed into the field. However, I can also enable autocorrection at the same time.

Does anyone know what happens in that case? If my password is "bananas" and I start typing it into the field, it's not helpful for the text to be obscured, if the it's is also going to be autocorrected.

Comment: While it's an interesting thought experiment - shouldn't you be explicitly disabling this anyways. Along with capitalization etc..

Comment: I would if I was writing the code - I'm not.  I'm reviewing someone else's code, and I don't want to make work for them if it's not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael Kernahan said, this is an interesting thought experiment. I had never thought about it before but just to be sure that my hunch that the field *wouldn't* autocorrect held true, I created a small Xcode project to test the concept.

After creating the (admittedly crude) interface in IB, I used the default `omw` autocorrect to test the field as a control. Without specifically enabling autocorrect on the field, the autocorrection occurred.

[image: Autocorrect works!]

I set the field to be secure by calling

```
[secureTextField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```

and running the test again. The test failed and the field did not autocorrect.

[image: Autocorrect doesn't work :(]

Finally, as you describe in your question, I set the secure text field's `autoCorrectionType` to `UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes` and the test failed yet again.

[image: Autocorrect doesn't work yet again :(]

---

To answer your question more briefly, based on these tests **setting `UITextField` to take secure input disables the autocorrective attributes of the field**, regardless of whether they are explicitly enabled or not (as expected and as it should be).